# Facebook redirect page after login

Tags: php, facebook, redirect

While trying to loggin on the facebook app I'm developping, after calling:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
```

I'm being redirected to this page:

```
https://www.mywebpage.com/facebook/apps.facebook.com/myappname#_=_
```

witch is not a valid page, and I imagine the right page to be redirected should be:

apps.facebook.com/myappname

Does anyone knows how to solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [php redirect](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ht/phpredirection.htm)

or lots of similar ways to redirect straight?

Harry

Comment: Thanks for that, and sorry for the silly question. I'm new on that and thought this was something with the app configuration.

Answer (score 2):

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'redirect_uri' => YOUR_CANVAS_URL
    ))
```

YOUR_CANVAS_URL should start with 'https://'